# How to derive The Mathematical expression for this decision Boundary line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to derive a mathematical expression that describes the best position for this green line from the two classifications of objects. i mean by "The Best" that the distance between the line and each classification should be equal as possible.

[Plot for the Decision boundary that separates the 2 classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nIea.png)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Alright. The problem within the context of Neural Network and i need to figure out a way to do the best separation of these 2 classifications of data using Linear Algebra.